# In R, do an operation temporarily using a setting such as working directory

Tags: r

I'm almost certain I've read somewhere how to do this. Instead of having to save the current option (say working directory) to a variable, change the w.d, do an operation, and then revert back to what it was, doing this inside a function akin to "with" relative to attach/detach. A solution just for working directory is what I need now, but there might be a more generic function that does that sort of things? Or ain't it?

So to illustrate... The way it is now:

```
curdir <- getwd()
setwd("../some/place")
# some operation
setwd(curdir)
```

The way it is in my wildest dreams:

```
with.dir("../some/place", # some operation)
```

I know I could write a function for this, I just have the impression there's something more readily available and generalizable to other parameters too.

Thanks

Comment: maybe `?on.exit` would help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is an idiom for this in some of R's base plotting functions

```
op <- par(no.readonly = TRUE)

# par(blah = stuff)
# plot(stuff)

par(op)
```

that is so unbelievably crude as to be fully portable to `options()` and `setwd()`.

Fortunately it's also easy to implement a crude wrapper:

```
with_dir <- function(dir, expr) {
    old_wd <- getwd()
    setwd(dir)
    result <- evalq(expr)
    setwd(old_wd)
    result
}
```

I'm no wizard with nonstandard evaluation so `evalq` could be unstable somehow. More on NSE in [an old write-up by Lumley](http://developer.r-project.org/nonstandard-eval.pdf) and also in [Wickham's *Advanced R*](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html), but it's dense stuff and I haven't wrapped my head around it all yet.

**edit:** as per Ben Bolker's comment, it's probably better to use `on.exit` for this:

```
with_dir <- function(dir, expr) {
    old_wd <- getwd()
    on.exit(setwd(old_wd))
    setwd(dir)
    evalq(expr)
}
```

From the R docs:

> `on.exit` records the expression given as its argument as needing to be executed when the current function exits (either naturally or as the result of an error). This is useful for resetting graphical parameters or performing other cleanup actions.

Comment: Thanks for the reference... And I too find the whole area of substitute/eval/parse/deparse/quote "area" of functions is really not easy to grasp.

Comment: @DominicComtois Hadley's book does a very good job, you just need to read it very carefully and actually work through the examples and exercises yourself (something I haven't quite done yet). In this case, `evalq` by default evaluates its argument in the environment from which `with_dir` was called. So if you call `with_dir` from inside another function, I'm pretty sure it will be evaluated within that function and not, say, in the global environment.

Comment: @DominicComtois also R's own inconsistent terminology and function naming doesn't help clarify the situation.

Comment: I'll definitely give it a shot and let you know. And yeah, I know. Sometimes I miss Python (my former favorite language that I had to give up for its lack of statistical bagage) because of that... the more I know R, the more I see how messy it is. Powerful, but messy.

Comment: @DominicComtois funnily enough I recently picked up Python for its concise syntax and clean, powerful string manipulation functionality. For what it's worth, you can call R from iPython: http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/ipython/ipython/blob/3607712653c66d63e0d7f13f073bde8c0f209ba8/docs/examples/notebooks/rmagic_extension.ipynb

Comment: Good to know! If you like challenges and procrastination, have a look at "The Python Challenge", it's lots of fun!

Comment: I tested the last solution (following your edit) in a few different contexts and it works like a charm. Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 3):

What you're describing depends upon two things: detecting when you enter and leave a particular lexical scope, and defining a behavior to do on entrance and on exit. Python has these, called "Context Managers". This was a big deal when it was released, and many parts of Python's standard library now behave like context managers, and have to define the "enter" and "exit" behavior in explicitly, or by leveraging some clever inheritance scheme.

```
with.default
function (data, expr, ...) 
eval(substitute(expr), data, enclos = parent.frame())
<bytecode: 0x07d02ccc>
<environment: namespace:base>
```

R's `with` function works *sort of* like a context manager, because it can pass scopes around easily. That said, this doesn't give you the "enter" and "exit" operations for free. Especially consider that the current working directory isn't an entry in the current scope, but a state of the R interpreter, which can only be queried or changed by function calls behind the `.Internal` shield.

You can easily define your own object types to have methods that are context manager-like for the `with` generic function, as well as writing and registering methods for other types you commonly use, but it is not part of the base R language.